# Bad algorithm to compare 2 json files

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to compare two json files in order to detect additions, deletions and modifications.
I've got 3 functions for each but I noticed that if my function to detect additions have the second file with less objects than the first, it's bugging.
I'm recreating a JSON with all the additions.
I don't know how to perfect this algorithm for this case (where there is additions and deletions and it's making a second json file with less objects)

JSON examples :

```
var tab1 = { "user": [{ "name": "Jhon", "age": "18" }, { "name": "Danny", "age": "20" }, { "name": "Benoit", "age": "20" }] };
var tab2 = { "user": [{ "name": "Ted", "age": "20" }, { "name": "Bernard", "age": "20" }] };
```

So here is my function :

`nb_add` is the number of additions, `add_1` is the first addition detected

```
    $scope.detectAdd = function (x, y) {
            if (x !== y) {
                var tmp;
                var nb_add = 0;
                var add_1 = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < y["user"].length; i++) {
                    if (x["user"][i].name !== y["user"][i].name)
                        nb_add++;
                }

                var i = 0;
                do {
                    if (x["user"][i].name === y["user"][i].name)
                        add_1++;
                    i++;
                }
                while (i <= nb_ajout);

                var tmp = "[{" + '"name":' + '"' + y["user"][ajout_1].name + '",' + '"age":' + '"' + y["user"][ajout_1].age + '"}';
                var i = add_1 + 1;
                if (nb_add > 1) {
                    do {
                        if (x["user"][i].name != y["user"][i].name) {
                            tmp += ",{" + '"name":' + '"' + y["user"][i].name + '",' + '"age":' + '"' + y["user"][i].age + '"}';
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    while (i <= nb_add - 1);
                }
                tmp += "]";
                JSON.parse(tmp);
            }

        }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample json file to better understand the expected object properties.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: how hoes this function do anything besides wasting time? It has no side-effect and no return value, so all the work it does goes to the bin. And what **exactly** is this function supposed to do?

Comment: Yes but I took the wrong habit to use functions all the time I didn't know that void existing also in Javascript

Comment: JS is built on functions. There's nothing wrong with functions. And this comment didn't address any of my questions. A: Your function doesn't do anything *(that leaves the function in any way)*; you could as well just count to 1000000. and B: what exactly should this function do? How should these two arrays be compared? Because telling by your code, you're not talking about diffing these two objects, but instead it boils down to somehow comparing the usernames in these two arrays. But how? How should they be compared? You didn't explain anything about your algorithm